# GWTP & Singleton

Tags: gwt, maven

Есть простой презентер. При объявлении класса синглетона

```
private RandomString randomString = RandomString.getInstance();
```

Получаю ошибку

```
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:121)]
[INFO] 
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:120)]
[INFO]  -> by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder [@Inject constructor of by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView]
[INFO] 
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/DesktopGinjectorProvider.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 8: Failed to resolve 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector' via deferred binding
```

RandomString

```
...

    private RandomString() {

    }

    private static class RandomStringHolder {
        private final static RandomString instance = new RandomString();
    }

    public static RandomString getInstance() {
        return RandomStringHolder.instance;
    }
...
```

С чем это может быть связанно? Без объявления RandomString проект собирается